# Is it possible to query multiple AWS Cloudsearch fields for the same value without repeating?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Using AWS Cloudsearch, I need to query 2 separate fields for the same value using a structured (compound) query e.g.

```
(and (or name:'john smith') (or curr_addr:'123 someplace' other_addr:'123 someplace'))
```

This query works, but I'm wondering if it's necessary to repeat the value for each field that I want to search against. Is there some way to specify the value only once e.g. `curr_addr+other_addr:'123 someplace'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct way to structure your compound query.  From the AWS documentation, you'll see that they structure their example query the same way:

```
(and title:'star' (or actors:'Harrison Ford' actors:'William Shatner')(not actors:'Zachary Quinto'))
```

From [Constructing Compound Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-compound-queries.html)

You *may* be able to get around this by listing the more repetitive fields in the query options (`q.options`), and then specify the field for the rest of the fields.  The `fields` list is sort of a fallback for when you don't specify which field you are searching in a compound query.  So if you list the address fields there, and then only specify the `name` field in your query, you may get close to the behavior you're looking for.

**Query options**

```
q.options={fields: ['curr_addr','other_addr']}
```

**Query**

```
(and (or name:'john smith') (or '123 someplace'))
```

But this approach would only work for one set of repetitive fields, so it's not a silver bullet by any means.

From [Search API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/search-api.html#search-request) (see `q.options` => `fields`)